# Adding line numbers in a file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to master working with files in C, and I have a bump which I can't pass. I have been searching all day for information but I can't seem to find what I am looking for. I would like to number the lines in a file. For example, if I type in information about a book (let's say: Name, Air-date and id), I would expect something like this in my file:

```
1. Name:Dave Air-Date:1997 id:123
```

And I would like this to update itself. Say I close the program and run it again, the counting should start from 2.

My only problem is numbering the lines. Could someone point me in the right direction how to do this, or show me a sample source code?

Comment: If you're looking for line numbers while editing, `vim` allows you to type `:set nu` to add line numbers to the display and `:set nonu` to turn them off.  There are programs such as `pr` and `nl` on Unix platforms to number lines in files (and you'd use `sed` or something similar to remove the numbers).  If, as seems possible, you have an exercise to do which means numbering lines as they're read, then you can use `fgets()` to read lines and it is trivial to print a number when you output the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process each character one by one, and increment a counter that you print before the character when you encounter a carriage return (`\n`).

In pseudo-code:

```
lineNumber = 1;
Open the file
While ((c = read a character) is not EOF)
    If (c is \n)
        Print "lineNumber", then increment it
    Print c
End while
Close the file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late, but I hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  /* user input */
  char text[50];
  char res[100] = "";
  printf("Enter a short story (<100 characters): ");
  char ch;
  char *ptr = text;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    *ptr++ = ch;
  }
  printf("\nYou've entered this text:\n");
  printf("%s\n", text);

  /* append and create a new text */
  strcat(res, "0: ");
  char *qtr = text;
  int i = 1;
  while (*qtr != '\0') {
    if (*qtr != '\n') {
      char temp[2];
      sprintf(temp, "%c", *qtr);
      strcat(res, temp);
    } else {
      char temp[5];
      sprintf(temp, "\n%d: ", i++);
      strcat(res, temp);
    }
    qtr++;
  }

  printf("\nLine number added: \n");
  printf("%s\n", res);

  return 0;
}
```